# pyspark dataframe doesn't change after some processing

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I create a dateframe, and use window function to get the accumulative value, but after use the function,df and df.select() show with different row order

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local[8]').appName("SparkByExample.com").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", '50')

# create dataframe
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType,FloatType,LongType,ArrayType
data = [(1,1,2),
        (1,2,2),
        (1,3,2),   
        (1,2,1),
        (2,1,2),
        (2,3,2),
        (2,2,1),
        (3,1,2),
        (3,3,2),
        (3,2,1)]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("col1", IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("col2", IntegerType(),True), \
    StructField("col3", IntegerType(),True)])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df.show()
```

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   1|   2|
|   1|   2|   2|
|   1|   3|   2|
|   1|   2|   1|
|   2|   1|   2|
|   2|   3|   2|
|   2|   2|   1|
|   3|   1|   2|
|   3|   3|   2|
|   3|   2|   1|
+----+----+----+
```

```
# this is window fuction to get the accumulative value
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window().partitionBy(F.col('col1')).orderBy(F.col('col2'))

def f(lag_val, current_val):
    value = 0
    if lag_val != current_val:
        value = 1
    return value
    
# register udf so we can use with our dataframe
func_udf = F.udf(f, IntegerType())

print(id(df))
df = df.withColumn("new_column", func_udf(F.lag("col3").over(w), df['col3'])).withColumn('new_column2', F.sum('new_column').over(w.partitionBy(F.col('col1')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
df.show()
```

```
+----+----+----+----------+-----------+
|col1|col2|col3|new_column|new_column2|
+----+----+----+----------+-----------+
|   3|   1|   2|         1|          1|
|   3|   2|   1|         1|          2|
|   3|   3|   2|         1|          3|
|   2|   1|   2|         1|          1|
|   2|   2|   1|         1|          2|
|   2|   3|   2|         1|          3|
|   1|   1|   2|         1|          1|
|   1|   2|   2|         0|          1|
|   1|   2|   1|         1|          2|
|   1|   3|   2|         1|          3|
+----+----+----+----------+-----------+
```

```
test = df.select('col1','col2','col3')
test.show()
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   1|   2|
|   1|   2|   2|
|   1|   3|   2|
|   1|   2|   1|
|   2|   1|   2|
|   2|   3|   2|
|   2|   2|   1|
|   3|   1|   2|
|   3|   3|   2|
|   3|   2|   1|
+----+----+----+
```

we can see that the row order of 'col1','col2','col3' of df and test are different, but test shows the original order of df, this could be because of action and transformation, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since on a python dataframe packages, sometimes it will automatically alter the order after some functions are executed. If you are referring to debugging, I suggest you break down your code as the following:

```
df = df.withColumn("new_column", func_udf(F.lag("col3").over(w), df['col3'])).withColumn('new_column2', F.sum('new_column').over(w.partitionBy(F.col('col1')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
```

to something like this

```
df = df.withColumn("new_column", func_udf(F.lag("col3").over(w), df['col3']))
df_partition = w.partitionBy(F.col('col1')).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))
df = df.withColumn('new_column2', F.sum('new_column').over(df_partition)
```

You should further break those lines into smaller function until you understand what each function does.

Comment: Thank u, I know pandas dataframe will not have this kind of issue,this is happeded on pyspark dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you do `explain()` to check the query plans,

```
test.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan ExistingRDD[col1#255,col2#256,col3#257]

df.explain()
== Physical Plan ==
Window [sum(cast(new_column#288 as bigint)) windowspecdefinition(col1#255, col2#256 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS new_column2#295L], [col1#255], [col2#256 ASC NULLS FIRST]
+- *(4) Sort [col1#255 ASC NULLS FIRST, col2#256 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col1#255, 50), true, [id=#553]
      +- *(3) Project [col1#255, col2#256, col3#257, pythonUDF0#389 AS new_column#288]
         +- BatchEvalPython [f(_we0#289, col3#257)], [pythonUDF0#389]
            +- Window [lag(col3#257, 1, null) windowspecdefinition(col1#255, col2#256 ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, -1, -1)) AS _we0#289], [col1#255], [col2#256 ASC NULLS FIRST]
               +- *(2) Sort [col1#255 ASC NULLS FIRST, col2#256 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
                  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(col1#255, 50), true, [id=#544]
                     +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[col1#255,col2#256,col3#257]
```

You can see that the query optimizer knew that the `test` dataframe only requires columns from the original dataframe, so it skipped all the transformations for the new columns in `df` because they are irrelevant. That's why the dataframe had the same order as the original dataframe.

But for the new `df` with additional columns, sorting was performed in the window functions, so the order of the dataframe changed.

Comment: Thank u so much, but In that case how can I know which df will be called for other programming work?